# Multiple users group accessing multiple database set in mysqli and php using email

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication

I have a database called `school_name1` and a second one called `school_name2` and so on. Each database has multiple tables like `students`, `courses`, `batches` and so on.

If `school_name1` students log in they should go to school 1 database and access the tables within that. And for `school_name2` they should access school 2 database and get all the tables within that.

Here's my basic connection so far. How do I get the log in information to send them to relevant database?

```
<?php

// connecting the db
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = 'school_name1';

// Connecting the Database
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$con) {
        die("<br /> <br />Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

Comment: How do you define that a student belongs to `school_name1`?

Comment: each student will have their own email id in the school. which we can use it as unique?

Comment: If the domain part of the e-mail address is unique/different for each school, you can use that information to connect to the respective database.

Comment: @IcedAnt why so complex and unreliable?

Comment: @YourCommonSense feel free to provide a better solution

Comment: @IcedAnt the guy below has one

Comment: @YourCommonSense how is it different from my solution? He could just as easily have a dropdown to select domain.

Comment: easily. that's the word

Comment: @YourCommonSense do you have a solution?

Comment: ok, then we will try.